# How to fix format error for char* and char**

Tags: c

i'm writing a kind of phonebook program and i'm using `typedef struct` to store the name and number of the people. The user will input name and number as a string format, but when i try to scan it, the compiler gives me an error saying "format specifies type `char *` but the argument has type `char **`. Any solution on this? i really don't understand what it means. **Error is on first loop on both scans** any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *name;
    char *number;
}
person;

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    scanf("%i", &n);
    person people[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", &people[i].name); // these 2 lines are buggy
        scanf("%s", &people[i].number);
    }

    char *findName;
    scanf("%s", &findName);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(people[i].name, findName) == 0)
        {
            printf("%s\n", people[i].number);
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably you want `char *name` -> `char name[100];`, where 100 is the maximum size of the name. Same for `number` and `findName`

Comment: You also forgot `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: Note: You don't need the `typedef` in `typedef struct` in C++. Just `struct` is fine. But this looks like C, so why is the question tagged C++?

Comment: Please don't spam language tags, use only the one you actually program in. Especially since your code is invalid in one of the tagged languages.

Comment: `person people[n];` is not provided in the C++ standard (a VLA) and is only offered by some C++ compilers as a non-standard extension. Both `name` and `number` are uninitialized pointer members of the struct. You must allocate storage for each before attempting to copy data to them. And since they are both already pointers, you don't take the address of them when used with `scanf`...

Comment: I apologise for tagging c++ as well, thought i could also include c++ because its quite close. Thank you for correcting my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
scanf("%s", &people[i].name);
```

is wrong for *two* reasons:

1. First of all the `%s` format expects a `char *` argument. By using the address-of operator you get a value of type `char **`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.
2. If you remove the address-of operator you will pass an uninitialized pointer, it's not pointing anywhere valid. This means `scanf` will write the string to some seemingly random location in memory. Again this leads to *undefined behavior*.

A simple way to solve the second issue, you could change the structure to contain *arrays* of characters instead, as in:

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[64];
    char number[64];
}
person;
```

Then use a limit in the format so the `scanf` function will not attempt to read a string longer than the arrays:

```
scanf("%63s", people[i].name);  // The array decays to a pointer to its first element
```

Note that the length in the format is 63, so the string null-terminator will fit in the array.

Answer (score 1):

**Never use the `"%s"` format with `scanf()`. You cannot use it safely.**

The problem is, that the user controls how many characters will get written into the memory buffer, but the program needs to supply the memory buffer without knowing how many characters the user is actually going to input. The result is invariable buffer overrun vulnerabilities of your program. Don't do this.

Instead, use allocating input functions. For `scanf()`, you need to add the `"m"` modifier:

```
scanf("%ms", &people[i].name);
```

This changes the expected argument type from `char*` to `char**`, it will `malloc()` a sufficiently sized buffer for you, and store the address at the given location. I.e, this call does precisely what you want it to do. Just don't forget to `free()` the resulting string once you are done with it.

The `"m"` modifier works with the `"%ms"`, `"%m["` and `"%mc"` conversion specifiers, i.e. all the conversions that can output a string of unknown length.

(The other allocating input functions that you should keep in mind are `getline()` and `getdelim()`.)

Answer (score 0):

`findname` is already a `char *`.
You ask for reference of this value, it represent `char **`

`scanf("%s", &findName);`

Try this :

`scanf("%s", findName);`

Comment: Yes need a malloc or calloc at initialization with size, if you want to use dynamic memory

Comment: The struct has a bad initialization if it is an array

Comment: yea turned out i need to allocate memory and it's all good. Thanks for the help guys. Though i still don't quite understand why i need to change my char *name into an array in the struct.

Comment: if you don't change it to an array of `char`s the `sizeof(person)`  in a `malloc(n * sizeof(person))` will only have space for n pointers, that is on a 64 bits system,  for let's say 2 persons 16 bytes.  And those points will be pointing nowhere as there is no more memory allocated for storing the actual characters of the string. There is however a way to allocate dynamically the size of the string, using scanf("%ms"). Posting another answer with that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with dynamically allocated memory and `scanf` with `%ms`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *name;
    char *number;
}
person;

int main(void)
{
    int n = 0;
    char *findName ;
    scanf("%i", &n);
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    
    person* people = (person*)malloc(n * sizeof(person));
    
    if (people == NULL) return 1;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        person p = people[i];
        printf("Enter Name and number:\n");
        printf("Number: ");
        scanf("%ms", &(p.number));
        printf("Name: ");
        scanf("%ms", &(p.name));
        people[i] = p;
    }
    
    printf("Enter name to search: ");
    scanf("%ms", &findName);
    printf("Searching for: %s\n", findName);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        person p = people[i];
        
        if(strcmp(p.name, findName) == 0)
        {
            printf("Number for %s is %s\n", p.name, p.number);
        }
    }
    free(findName);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        //notice how we have to free the strings for each name and number, 
        // and not just the people array 
        free(people[i].name);
        free(people[i].number);
    }
    free(people);
    return 0;
}
```